# How to get a sublist of a list based on another list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

```
a = [12,3,8,14]
b = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want to find the sublist of elements in `b` so that the corresponding item in `a` is greater than `10`:

```
b_even = [b[i] for i, e in enumerate(a) if e > 10]
```

---

This code works OK, but are there any easier ways like `b[a>10]` in R?

Comment: You already have the "Pythonic" way to do this with a list.  The shorter syntax you suggest is available with `numpy` arrays.

Comment: In Python, I would use `[y for x,y in zip(a,b) if  x > 10]`. But no, Python `list` objects do not support vectorized operations. Use `numpy` and `pandas` for that

Comment: between the zip and numpy approaches, which one is faster?

Answer (score 1):

Zip?

```
print([[*i] for i in list(zip(a,b)) if i[0] > 10])
```

> ```
> [[12, 'a'], [14, 'd']]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The regular solution is to use `zip`:

```
res = [i for i, j in zip(a, b) if j > 10]
```

A functional alternative is possible via `operator.itemgetter` and `enumerate`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = itemgetter(*(idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val > 10))(b)
```

For vectorised functionality / syntax, you can use a 3rd party library such as NumPy.

Comment: Thanks! This helps

Comment: @Jensen, No problem. You should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer that helped (green tick on left).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = b[np.where(a>10)]
```

Comment: is the numpy array approach faster than zip for list?

Comment: I have not tested, but numpy is usually faster than zip and list

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would have been what you have but I could get the same results using;

```
[s[1] for s in zip(a, b) if s[0] > 10]
```